# suggestion for processing huge amount of data on a single node system

Tags: python, mysql, mongodb, data-processing

I have to load huge amount of data(stackoverflow dump), process it and generate files for some machine learning application.

Operations are..

1. Parse an XML file and load it to some db(NoSql or SQL). I use a SAX parser.
2. Do some operations, basically group by(or aggregate) on the database.
3. Then generate CSV files. CSV file generation is on-demand. It must not take more than 2 minutes for 10,000 records.

My constraints are Python is the language I can only use and everything should run on a dual core CPU(no distributed system).

I tried it using mysql and processing 21 million records took days(I created hell lot of indexes and aggregate operations). Now, I use mongodb, it still takes a lot of time.

Can somebody suggest me some technology which I can use to make it faster(like time taken can be 4/5 hours).

Comment: Creating indexes blindly doesn't help. Which part took time? Fetching data and sticking it into CSV or inserting into the db?

Comment: mostly the data processing, the aggregate operations. Fetching and writing was not a big concern.

Comment: What's the hardware that you use to run MySQL (CPU, HDD, RAM)? How much RAM is allocated to MySQL? Have you profiled queries using EXPLAIN to see if you're I/O or CPU bound? Swapping software can't help unless you are certain it can't do the job.